# How to use gtest to count the number of test classes?

Tags: c++, class, installation, count, googletest

I tried to count the number of test classes, like this:

```
int classCount = 0;
class TestClass2 : public testing::Test {
protected:
    static void SetUpTestCase() {

    }
    static void TearDownTestCase() {

    }

    virtual void SetUp() { classCount++; }
    virtual void TearDown() {}
};

TEST(TestClass1, classCount) {
    cout << typeid(*this).name() << endl;
    EXPECT_EQ(1, classCount);
}
```

Unfortunately, the `classCount` is 0. I was expecting that when TestClass1_xxxx class is initialized, the `classCount` will +1 by `virtual void SetUp() { classCount++; }`. But actually it's not called. I added `cout` inside `virtual void SetUp() { classCount++; }` but still saw not console output.

So my question is, when is `virtual void SetUp() {}` begin called? Is it called automatically in some way?

Comment: It should be `void SetUp() override {}` in modern C++.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the whole class and the code will still compile.

```
int classCount = 0;

TEST(TestClass1, classCount) {
    cout << typeid(*this).name() << endl;
    EXPECT_EQ(1, classCount);
}
```

Because `class TestClass2` is a test fixture class and should be used with the macro `TEST_F`.

```
int classCount = 0;
class TestClass2 : public testing::Test {
protected:
    static void SetUpTestCase() {

    }
    static void TearDownTestCase() {

    }

    void SetUp() override { classCount++; }
    void TearDown() override {}
};
//  ▼▼
TEST_F(TestClass1, classCount) {
    cout << typeid(*this).name() << endl;
    EXPECT_EQ(1, classCount);
}
```

---

What is you real problem? That code smells [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).